# When exceeding the data quota, what is the best way to "split up" this github repo?

Tags: git, github, quota

I added several ~1M files to (an already large) repo. Upon the next add/commit/push, I received this error:

```
Git LFS: (0 of 1 files) 0 B / 28.35 KB   
batch response: http: This repository is over its data quota. Purchase more data packs to restore access.
Docs: https://help.github.com/articles/purchasing-additional-storage-and-bandwidth-for-a-personal-account/
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO_NAME
```

Without paying for more data packs (which isn't feasible on my current budget, though I am doing research with an academic account with GitHub), how would one resolve this issue?

Perhaps this is a straightforward question, but I haven't been able to find the guidelines online: what is the recommended way for users to split this repo into two? I suspect one would simply create a new repo, move these files over to this, and delete these files in the previous repo (deleting all branches in the process).

Are there other options available? It's very strange----most of these files are less than 1MB....naturally if there was one *large* file causing the problem, then this process would be a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge you're going to run into is that you really can't make a repository any smaller without rewriting its history. If you're OK with rewriting history, you can use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to modify history in bulk, e.g. `--index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/big/file'` (or use `--subdirectory-filter` to limit the repository to a single subfolder).

I'm not certain how you would go about purging/splitting the files that have been stored on GitHub by Git-LFS, though.

> It's very strange----most of these files are less than 1MB....naturally if there was one large file causing the problem, then this process would be a bit more straightforward.

If the 1MB files are uncompressible and change often (or there are just a lot of them), it's expected that the repository would get relatively large pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a bit unclear regarding what git commands you're recommending----what would be the best way to revise my history to remove the latest commands (thus making the repo under the limit again), and then start deleting/moving files?

Comment: The simplest way to "undo" the most recent commits is to just do something like `git push -f origin master~50:master`, which will move `master` back 50 commits (technically, back 50 first parents, if any are merges). However, even if you delete any newer branches GitHub will _still_ have reflog references to the old `master`; support may be able to help.

I'm not sure how it would work with Git-LFS, but you might be better off leaving the current repo as-is and then creating new repos from parts split apart using `filter-branch`.

Comment: The problem in my case was that Git-LFS was both overloaded with data and tracking a repo it shouldn't have been. However, I think this answer is useful for the general problem of "too big" repos.

Comment: Well good luck - decidedly not trivial to make a Git repo smaller after the fact!

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051553/github-repository-data-limit-reached) was resolved by contacting GitHub Support.