# How to check the size of each repositories using Git-LFS?

Tags: git, github

I received the message:" This repository is over its data quota." when pushing from the local. Then I go to GitHub website and check under setting/billing/ to see the GitLFS storage, which is much larger than 1GB(around 10+GB). However, at my best knowledge, I have never used that many GB of storage. So is it possible to check which particular repository that takes that much storage?

There is a 'Repositories' tab under 'setting' which summaries all repositories' storage usage, but when I check there, I didn't see any repositories that use 10+ GB storage. So any suggestions that I should try? Thank you!

Comment: When you checked Git LFS Data and see the breakdown of the usage. Did you check the numbers for both the Bandwidth and Storage?

Comment: Yes. I found the bandwidth usage is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since Sept. 2021 (2 years later), this is now possible:

> ### [Viewing LFS Usage by Repository](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-03-viewing-lfs-usage-by-repository/)
>
> Organization owners and individual users can now view their LFS usage by repository.
>
> For further info, see the [documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-git-large-file-storage/viewing-your-git-large-file-storage-usage).
>
> [image: lfs-data -- https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/8298818/131998565-aa369487-8c4f-411d-8a2d-d5b64ce77ddd.png?w=754&ssl=1]